# custom Analyzer using ASCIIFoldingFilter not replacing diacritics

Tags: c#, java, lucene, lucene.net, diacritics

We have an issue with a custom Lucene.NET Analyzer which uses [ASCIIFoldingFilter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/trunk/C%23/src/Lucene.Net/Analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.cs) and LowerCaseFilter.

While indexing our content, the lower case filter works and makes all terms low case but the ASCIIFoldingFilter leaves the diacritics untouched (there are no errors but characters like **őŏő** are not replaced with **o**, they are untouched and appear like this in the index - I would have expected this to work or fail not do nothing).

The relevant code is like this:

```
public TokenStream TokenStream(String fieldName, TextReader reader) {
  Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
  TokenStream stream = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
  stream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(stream);
  return new LowerCaseFilter(stream);
}
```

Are there some additional steps that need to be performed to use the ASCIIFoldingFilter?

Is there some working Java example that I could adapt to Lucene.NET?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I managed to fix this. It was a misconfiguration issue. The custom analyzer was not used, another one was used which just did low case. The custom filter is now working correctly. Sorry!

Comment: The codepoints for the accented o-s you showed ('\u0151' and '\u014f') are explicitly handled by ASCIIFoldingFilter.  Consider the possibility that the strings are not normalized.

Comment: @Hans Passant: can you please further explai this part of your comment: *Consider the possibility that the strings are not normalized*. Am I to understand that I should do something to the input before passing it to the ASCIIFoldingFilter?

Comment: Check out the string.Normalize() method in the MSDN Library.  Just guessing.  Debugging this would certainly be the best approach.

Comment: @user9648321, add this as a answer so this question can be marked as resolved.